# Angular - Pegar dados de um object json e colocar em uma table junto com outro object

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

Olá, queria saber se alguém poderia me ajudar, hoje eu tenho uma table que recebe dados de um component(Medias), eu tenho outro component que é playlists, no playlists eu associo as medias a uma playlist.

Na table de medias, eu queria pode monstra em uma coluna a quantidade de playlists essa media tem. Mas infelizmente não estou entendendo como fazer, já puxei os dados das playlists para fazer a associação.

Component:

```
@Input('table-data')
public tableData: MediaModel[] = [];
@Input('table-data2')
public tableDataPl: PlaylistModel[] = [];

public data2Render: MediaModel[] = [];
public data2RenderPl: PlaylistModel[] = [];

ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges) {
    if (changes['tableData']) {
        if (!changes['tableData'].firstChange) {
            this.dtElement.dtInstance.then((dtInstance: DataTables.Api) => {
                dtInstance.destroy();
                this.data2Render = changes['tableData'].currentValue;
                this.dtTrigger.next();
            });                             
        }
    }       

    if (changes['tableDataPl']) {
        if (!changes['tableDataPl'].firstChange) {                          
            console.log(this.tableDataPl.map(x => x.itens));                
        }
    }  
}
```

Console.log:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

html:

```
            <thead>
            <tr role="row">
                <td>Nome da Mídia</td>
                <td>Tipo de Mídia</td>
                <td>Ações</td>
                <td>PlayList Quantidade</td>
            </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
            <tr *ngFor="let media of data2Render; let i = index">
                <td>{{ media.filename }}</td>
                <td>{{ getMediaType(media.file_type) }}</td>
                <td>??????????</td>
            </tr>
            </tbody>
```

Answer (score 0):

Acredito que criando uma função de agrupamento você possa resolver seu problema.

Exemplo:

```
var list = [
    {name: "1", lastname: "foo1", age: "16"},
    {name: "2", lastname: "foo", age: "13"},
    {name: "3", lastname: "foo1", age: "11"},
    {name: "4", lastname: "foo", age: "11"},
    {name: "5", lastname: "foo1", age: "16"},
    {name: "6", lastname: "foo", age: "16"},
    {name: "7", lastname: "foo1", age: "13"},
    {name: "8", lastname: "foo1", age: "16"},
    {name: "9", lastname: "foo", age: "13"},
    {name: "0", lastname: "foo", age: "16"}
];
```

Resultado esperado agrupado por lastname:

```
var result = [
    [
        {name: "1", lastname: "foo1", age: "16"},
        {name: "5", lastname: "foo1", age: "16"}, 
        {name: "8", lastname: "foo1", age: "16"}
    ],
    [
        {name: "2", lastname: "foo", age: "13"},
        {name: "9", lastname: "foo", age: "13"}
    ],
    [
        {name: "3", lastname: "foo1", age: "11"}
    ],
    [
        {name: "4", lastname: "foo", age: "11"}
    ],
    [
        {name: "6", lastname: "foo", age: "16"},
        {name: "0", lastname: "foo", age: "16"}
    ],
    [
        {name: "7", lastname: "foo1", age: "13"}
    ]         
];
```

Esse é uma possível solução:

```
function groupBy( array , f )
{
  var groups = {};
  array.forEach( function( o )
  {
    var group = JSON.stringify( f(o) );
    groups[group] = groups[group] || [];
    groups[group].push( o );  
  });
  return Object.keys(groups).map( function( group )
  {
    return groups[group]; 
  })
}

var result = groupBy(list, function(item)
{
  return [item.lastname, item.age];
});
```

Nesse caso está agrupando e basta exibir o length do array, mas você pode ajustar para realizar uma soma em um atributo novo, "totalPlaylists" por exemplo, e só exibir na tela diretamente.

Comment: Como eu faço pra capturar o item de uma dessas colunas do array?, não estou conseguindo =(

Comment: NO caso eu estou querendo fazer o contrario, ele hoje está agrupado, eu quero quebrar isso e colocar em um só como o seu codigo de criação do array

Comment: Coloca como você recebe os dados e como você precisa da saída. 
Se possível coloca sem ser imagem.